Receiving and opening a package on Yom Tov / Chag
I expect a package to arrive on Yom Tov (e.g. first day of Sukkot). If the contents of the package are (a) for a permitted use on chag and (b) created/fashioned before chag starts, am I permitted to open the package and use the contents?
Related: Receiving and opening a package on Shabbat

Hi, what's wrong with the answer to that question for this case? Nolad applies to Yom Tov too, and anyway, what specific difference between Shabbat and Yom Tov would apply to this question to make it different from the quoted question?

I'm not an expert on all the differences between Shabbat and Yom Tov, and so it would be really helpful having someone with more knowledge give an answer. One difference that comes to mind is that it is permitted to carry on Yom Tov.

This page makes a good case to lay out how nolad is probably more strict on Yom Tov than Shabbat, so if you rephrase this question to ask if the leniency given in the other answer would apply to Yom Tov, I think it would be a rather unique question, otherwise, if you are just asking if it is allowed or not allowed, the stringencies from the other answer do answer this pretty clearly. Either way, that answer getting attention is also useful - maybe there are other answers

Maybe I'm missing something. How is nolad relevant here, if the package is already made before Yom Tov?

*if the package is already made, and if it's ok to carry / transfer domains on Yom Tov

@JoshGrinberg Techum applies on Yom Tov (Shulchan Aruch OC 528:1, "יום טוב אין צריך עירובי חצרות ושיתופי מבואות אבל עירוב תחומין צריך").

But carrying many types of items outside the techum is permitted if for a (permissible) Yom Tov need, right? https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/12-06-02/
